# SaveAs works unless user selects file in SaveAsDialog

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the code below so users can "export" the Workbook they're working on. Basically, they're working in a Read-only master workbook, when they click the sub below it executes a SaveAs to a folder the user selects with the file name of whatever is in: Sheets("Master").Range("B5")

This works fine, the only problem is that if there's a '.xlsm' file in the folder the user selects and they click it to grab the filename, the saved Workbook name becomes "XXXXXX.xlsm.xlsm". If the user doesn't click anything and hits save it works fine.

Any ideas? Let me know if this wasn't clear

```
Sub ExportTrip()
Dim ActSheet As Worksheet
Dim ActBook As Workbook
Dim CurrentFile As String
Dim NewFile As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False    ' Prevents screen refreshing.

CurrentFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName

NewFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
    InitialFileName:=Sheets("Master").Range("B5"))

If NewFile <> "" And NewFile <> "False" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=NewFile & "xlsm", _
        FileFormat:=52, _
        Password:="", _
        WriteResPassword:="", _
        ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        CreateBackup:=False

    Set ActBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Workbooks.Open CurrentFile
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActBook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, needed to add file filter. See below:

```
Sub ExportTrip()
    Dim ActSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ActBook As Workbook
    Dim CurrentFile As String
    Dim NewFile As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False    ' Prevents screen refreshing.

    CurrentFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName   ' saves filename of current workbook

    NewFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
        InitialFileName:=Sheets("Master").Range("B5"), _
        FileFilter:="ARMS Export *.xlsm (*.xlsm),")   ' gets filename for exported workbook

       If NewFile <> "" And NewFile <> "False" Then         'if user doesn't pick name
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=NewFile, _
            FileFormat:=52, _
            Password:="", _
            WriteResPassword:="", _
            ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
            CreateBackup:=False

        Set ActBook = ActiveWorkbook 'declares variable for open workbook
        Workbooks.Open CurrentFile   'reopens original workbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActBook.Close                'closes exported workbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```